# Notification doesn't always show Pop Up

Tags: android, notifications, foreground-service

I'm using a foreground service with notifications. It it's important that my notification pops up by itself and not just when you drag down the top bar.
It's working most of the time. Except on Xiaomi phones. And weirdly enough it just stopped working on a Pixel 2 API 29 as well...
I know they don't show up on older APIs if there is no sound OR vibration. Maybe it has something to do with that.

```
StatusNotification statusNotification = new StatusNotification(getApplicationContext());
startForeground(1, statusNotification.notification());
```

...

```
public class StatusNotification {
    Context context;
    long[] shortVibration;

    StatusNotification(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        shortVibration = new long[] {0L, 100L, 0L};

// just {100L} doesn't vibrate at all
// but it has to be one short vibration and not the default one
// VibrationEffect.createOneShot() is only for Oreo and higher

        createNotificationChannel();
    }

    void createNotificationChannel(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationManager manager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

            NotificationChannel channel2 = new NotificationChannel("channel2", "Channel 2", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel2.setDescription("Channel 2");
            channel2.enableVibration(true);
            channel2.setSound(null, null);
            channel2.setVibrationPattern(shortVibration);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel2);
        }
    }

    Notification notification(){
        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "channel2")
                .setProgress(100,100, false)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setVibrate(shortVibration)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought... If the Pixel 2 stopped working (after it had worked in the past) perhaps you should check the phones notifications settings for your app. Perhaps the phone decided that the notifications were not of significant importance and demoted the priority.

Comment: I uninstalled it and deleted all channels manually. But who knows what else android might be "deciding" without letting the user/developer know. ;-)

Comment: It is becoming increasingly frustrating as an Android developer with the changes to diverse APIs (Notification, Location, ....) which must be compensated for through more extensive coding. Unfortunately, I have really don't any other suggestion for you, at this time. Good luck. I hope you get a solution to your issue...I'm sure I will need it in the near future!